# Understanding function with <|> operator

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation, monads, alternative-functor

I have the following type:

```
newtype Rep f a = Rep { runRep :: String -> f (String, a) }
```

The type `Rep f a` is a stateful computation that takes a `String` as the initial state and produces a `(String, a)` as the result of the computation. The result of the computation is wrapped in the functor `f`.

The Applicative instance for `Rep` is the following:

```
instance Monad f => Applicative (Rep f) where 
    pure x = Rep $ \s -> pure (s, x)
    Rep f <*> Rep x = Rep $ \s -> do 
        (s',rf)  <- f s 
        (s'',rx) <- x s'
        return (s'', rf rx)
```

And the Monad instance for `Rep` is the following:

```
instance Monad f => Monad (Rep f) where 
   return x = pure x 
   Rep a >>= f = Rep $ \s -> do
      (s', ya) <- a s
      let (Rep f') = f ya
      (s'', yf) <- f' s'
      pure (s'', yf)
```

The Alternative instance for `Rep` is the following:

```
instance (Monad f, Alternative f) => Alternative (Rep f) where 
    empty = Rep (const empty)
    Rep a <|> Rep b = Rep $ \s -> a s <|> b s
```

I have the following data types and function:

```
data TD = Empty | Fol TD TD | Letters [Char] | Str TD
data Res = Nil | Character Char | Cop Res Res | Special [Res]

findmatch :: (Monad f, Alternative f) => TD -> Rep f Res

findmatch (Str a) =
   frontAdd <$> findmatch a <*> findmatch (Str a)
   <|> pure (Special [])
      where
      frontAdd x (Special xs) = Special (x:xs)
      frontAdd _ _ = error "Not possible."
```

I am having trouble understanding the function above. The function `frontAdd` creates a `Special` value which contains a list of `[Res]`. `findmatch` returns `Rep f Res`. The line `frontAdd <$> findmatch a <*> findmatch (Str a)` applies `frontAdd` to the `Res` that is returned by `findmatch a` and `findmatch (Str a)`.

However, I am not sure how this line, with the pattern matching, works: `frontAdd x (Special xs) = Special (x:xs)`. Further, assuming that the functor `f` is `[ ]`, how would the `<|>` in `frontAdd <$> findmatch a <*> findmatch (Str a) <|> pure (Special [])` work? I know that if the functor `f` is `Maybe`, then `<|>` makes a left-biased choice, but I don't know how `<|>` works specifically for lists. In the documentation it states:

```
instance Alternative [] where
  empty = []
  (<|>) = (++) -- length xs + length ys = length (xs ++ ys)
```

How exactly does the concatenation work? Am I correct in saying that the result of `frontAdd <$> findmatch a <*> findmatch (Str a)` is concatenated with the empty list?

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if `f` is `[]`, then `pure (Special [])` is `[(Special [])]`, which is just `[Special []]`.

Second, list concatenation is the most natural thing, with

```
  [a, b, c, d, ...]  ++  [p, q, r, s, ...]
==
  [a, b, c, d, ...   ,    p, q, r, s, ...]
```

i.e.

```
(x:xs) ++ ys  =  x : (xs ++ ys)
[]     ++ ys  =             ys
```

which is to say,

```
   xs  ++ ys  =  foldr (:) ys xs
```

Thus

```
  [a, b, c]  <|>  [Special []]
==
  [a, b, c,        Special []]
```

and

```
  []         <|>  [Special []]
==
  [                Special []]
```

So no, `<|> pure (Special [])` does not concatenate with the empty list, but rather with a list of a `Special` wrapping the empty list.